# How to truncate the lines of a file?

Tags: line-truncation

I need to truncate the lines in a file to 24 characters, to feed to a small dot-matrix printer. How can I do this? I use doom emacs.

Answer (score 1):

From the shell:

```
cut -c1-24 FILE
```

In Emacs, interactively:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^\(.\{24\}\).+` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\1` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

phils has answered your question, but i wonder if you didn't mean that you wanted to limit the line lengths of a given file so that they'd all print within the constraint of your printer, rather than cutting your lines off.

if that is so, you need to set the `fill-column` to a value small enough, and then fill (wrap) your text, which limits your line lengths to the fill-column's value:

use `set-fill-column` (`C-x f` in vanilla emacs) to set a value for it.

then fill (wrap) your text with e.g. `fill-region` or `fill-paragraph`. to wrap a whole file you can just select whole buffer with `mark-whole-buffer` (`C-x h` in vanilla emacs) then run `fill-region`.